# Extract Album Art Image of MP3 URL

Tags: php, javascript, apache, audio-player, id3-tag

I am trying to extract album art image from mp3 URLs. I am basically having several MP3 URLs set, and I am playing them on a website, but I do not have album art of the songs. How can I get it? Is it possible to parse ID3 tags to get album art?

How do the window media player, vlc player and winamp player show album art of songs even if there is no such image in the songs directory?

I implemented the website using php and js.

Please help me out, thanks.
Kevindra

Comment: put some code what have you done recently?

Comment: I have crawled some mp3 files, and I have extracted basic ID3 tags using php like artist, title, album, genre etc.

I have a list of mp3 URLs,

I want a mechanism which can extract album art from that URL.

something like: function getAlbumArt( $URL ){
...

//After extracting save image in a directory. 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know VLC uses [freedb.freedb.org](http://freedb.freedb.org) to get his info, you could google for a API or build one to get the data through [freedb.freedb.org:8880/~cddb/cddb.cgi](http://freedb.freedb.org:8880/~cddb/cddb.cgi)

Comment: this is a great idea.. however I used last.fm APIs for extracting album arts of the songs. Thanks. :)